# Unable to bind address (Address already in use) in PHP

Tags: php, websocket, network-programming, phpwebsocket

I am working on chat application using websockets where I created client and server program. It is working properly on local host but as soon as I upload it to server it gives error message:

```
Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use
```

I have seen other answers from Stack Overflow but they are also not working. Below is my code for client and server. I tried to changes the port also but the same issue.

Both of these programs are inside test3 folder whose path I have given in client program as

```
var wsUri = "ws://xx.xx.xxx.xx:25763/test3/server.php";
```

Server.php

```
<?php
$host = 'xx.xx.xxx.xx'; //host
$port = '25763'; //port
$null = NULL; //null var
set_time_limit(0);

//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n");
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

//bind socket to specified host
socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");

//listen to port
socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

//create & add listning socket to the list
$clients = array($socket);

//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (true) {
    //manage multipal connections
    $changed = $clients;
    //returns the socket resources in $changed array
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

    //check for new socket
    if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
        $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accpet new socket
        $clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array

        $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024); //read data sent by the socket
        perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

        socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip); //get ip address of connected socket
        $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' connected'))); //prepare json data
        send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection

        //make room for new socket
        $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
        unset($changed[$found_socket]);
    }

    //loop through all connected sockets
    foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) { 

        //check for any incomming data
        while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)
        {
            $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
            $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 
            $user_name = $tst_msg->name; //sender name
            $user_message = $tst_msg->message; //message text
            $user_color = $tst_msg->color; //color

            //prepare data to be sent to client
            $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'usermsg', 'name'=>$user_name, 'message'=>$user_message, 'color'=>$user_color)));
            send_message($response_text); //send data
            break 2; //exist this loop
        }

        $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
            // remove client for $clients array
            $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
            socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
            unset($clients[$found_socket]);

            //notify all users about disconnected connection
            $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' disconnected')));
            send_message($response);
        }
    }
}
// close the listening socket
socket_close($sock);

function send_message($msg)
{
    global $clients;
    foreach($clients as $changed_socket)
    {
        @socket_write($changed_socket,$msg,strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}


//Unmask incoming framed message
function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Encode message for transfer to client.
function mask($text)
{
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}

//handshake new client.
function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port)
{
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
        {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
}
```

Client.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.chat_wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    padding: 10px;
    font: 12px 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
}
.chat_wrapper .message_box {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}
.chat_wrapper .panel input{
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 5px;
}
.system_msg{color: #BDBDBD;font-style: italic;}
.user_name{font-weight:bold;}
.user_message{color: #88B6E0;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>  
<?php 
$colours = array('007AFF','FF7000','FF7000','15E25F','CFC700','CFC700','CF1100','CF00BE','F00');
$user_colour = array_rand($colours);
?>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    //create a new WebSocket object.
    var wsUri = "ws://xx.xx.xxx.xx:25763/test3/server.php";     
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 

    websocket.onopen = function(ev) { // connection is open 
        $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connected!</div>"); //notify user
    }

    $('#send-btn').click(function(){ //use clicks message send button   
        var mymessage = $('#message').val(); //get message text
        var myname = $('#name').val(); //get user name

        if(myname == ""){ //empty name?
            alert("Enter your Name please!");
            return;
        }
        if(mymessage == ""){ //emtpy message?
            alert("Enter Some message Please!");
            return;
        }

        //prepare json data
        var msg = {
        message: mymessage,
        name: myname,
        color : '<?php echo $colours[$user_colour]; ?>'
        };
        //convert and send data to server
        websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    });

    //#### Message received from server?
    websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
        var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data); //PHP sends Json data
        var type = msg.type; //message type
        var umsg = msg.message; //message text
        var uname = msg.name; //user name
        var ucolor = msg.color; //color

        if(type == 'usermsg') 
        {
            $('#message_box').append("<div><span class=\"user_name\" style=\"color:#"+ucolor+"\">"+uname+"</span> : <span class=\"user_message\">"+umsg+"</span></div>");
        }
        if(type == 'system')
        {
            $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">"+umsg+"</div>");
        }

        $('#message').val(''); //reset text
    };

    websocket.onerror   = function(ev){$('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_error\">Error Occurred - "+ev.data+"</div>");}; 
    websocket.onclose   = function(ev){$('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connection Closed</div>");}; 
});
</script>
<div class="chat_wrapper">
<div class="message_box" id="message_box"></div>
<div class="panel">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" maxlength="10" style="width:20%"  />
<input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="80" style="width:60%" />
<button id="send-btn">Send</button>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Server Working Application:

```
<?php
// set some variables
$host = "xx.xx.xxx.xx:";
$port = 25763;
// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// bind socket to port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
// start listening for connections
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
// accept incoming connections
// spawn another socket to handle communication
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
// read client input
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
// clean up input string
$input = trim($input);
echo "Client Message : ".$input;
// reverse client input and send back
$output = strrev($input) . "\n";
echo $spawn;
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
// close sockets
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the port number on the server? Also check what all sockets are being used by running `netstat -an`

Comment: Yes i have changed the port number on the server but the same issue, i have created another program with sockets it is properly working on port number 25763. Please see my program i will be thankful to you.

Comment: The above program is properly working on localhost.

Comment: What do you mean by `i have created another program with sockets it is properly working on port number 25763`? Are you trying to run two programs with the same port number?

Comment: No i have created a sample program which is based on socket programming that one is working properly, that has no link with this one. If you want i can post that server code here.

Comment: The above code is for creating chatroom which i have taken from tis url http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket it is working on my local host but does not work when uploaded to server.

Comment: Check if this code works on your server. http://pastebin.com/xnmuXddp Just want to know if there is no problem with the server config.

Comment: No I have tried and the same error message occurs. What could be the problem please help to solve it....Thanks

Comment: I have added the working code for server at the last but i want to do it by websocket which i have posted earlier.

Comment: So your second server program works fine on the server but your first server fails to run?

Comment: After adding this code socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);  my first program runs fine but the example which have posted before is not working. Please help....

Comment: Sorry this is getting very confusing. Lets keep the localhost aside. Now which is your first program? Did you run my sample code provided in the link? Do any of the above program run or do all of them fail?

Comment: The above code Server.php and client.php is based on websocket they are not running on server, but Server Working Application is working on the same port on server and the program that you gave was also showing error message, I think there must be issue in my program because if one program runs and another does not on same port....

Comment: Firstly Server Working Application was also not running but after adding socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1); it start working.

Comment: You can download the working code from http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket and please see where i am wrong and how this code works on server because locally it is working fine....

Comment: If your Server Working Application code is working fine, try adding the functionality of server.php into Server Working Application code. It should work.

Comment: Just keep the socket code of Server Working Application and add rest of the code from server.php

Comment: I am not been able to do that because i thing both works on different concepts because the above uses websockets and i do not know much about websockets. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can u tell me whether this var wsUri = "ws://xx.xx.xxx.xx:25763/test3/server.php";    is the correct way to pass uri in websockets where t3 is subfolder under mainserver and server.php is the file.

Comment: Yes. The address is used by javascript which will connect to the given address. Also how are you running the server program in the server? Are you running it from the terminal?

Comment: I have changed the code and run it from browser but the same issue.Unable to bind address.